# Windows CE 6.0 and runtime link to Debug DLL /MDd

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I'm using Windows CE 6.0 R3 on an x86 PC. I've build the NK.bin and the SDK for the platform. But I've some problem to understand how can I build a console application with /MTd (Debug DLL).

If I try to build this:

```
// main.c with /MDd
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This work perfectly, but

```
// main.cpp /MDd
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

build but the application "crash". Seems that the C++ STD shared lib in debug version is not present on the target platform but the debug version of CRT is present.

What have I to do to build C++ application for windows ce 6.0 that link to the debug version of c++ library?

What have I to do to build C++ application for windows ce 6.0 that link to the debug version of c++ library? Have I've to change my Platform Builder?

Comment: It isn't very clear how the debug version of the crt ended up on your target, it shouldn't be there.  You are not allowed to copy it either.  Only ever deploy the release build of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fount the problem. The issue is that VS 2008 doesn't deply the debug version of CRT so I've have to deploy manualy the msvcr90d.dll on the target platform.
The msvcr90d.dll is located in $(VCInstallDir)/ce/bin/$(ARCHFAM).

Comment: I think there's a good reason that this isn't present by default, namely that the license doesn't allow you to distribute the debug libs. Note that you can use dependencywalker on the CE executables, too, only that e.g. coredll.dll will always be shown as missing.